# NLP - extract categories/tags from text

Tags: python, nltk, gensim

Does anyone have any idea or can give me directions about how I can extract categories from an article?

What I have is a corpus of few thousands of articles (about sports, news, buisness etc.) I can work with.

For example, if theres an article about sports I would like my program to know if its soccer or basketball (or somthing else) so the output will be somthing like:

soccer 90% basketball 10%

Comment: Do you have pre-classified articles, which you can use for training purpose?

Comment: I wish. then it would be an easy machine learning problem.. If I cant solve this it seems I would have to find a corpus with pre classified articles and build a training model of it..

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use some machine learning approaches to achieve this. What comes to my mind is using [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) statistic.

There is an online course on Coursera called "[Machine Learning Foundations: A Case Study Approach](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/machine-learning)" which teaches how to use `tf-idf` statistic on week 4 of the course.

Comment: I've already tried using tf-idf model. I get mediocre results. Mostly important words in the article (like Lakers, Kobe) but not categories.

Comment: err I'd grab the top say 30 keywords for all docs and run some type of clustering alg. Some K-means variant to start with the K=number of categories you want...

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have gold data for training, first you will need to create some.

For that, you will need to **define your classes** and define some **rules** which are obvious selection for each class,

```
article_text.contains("soccer") 
article_text.contains("Ronaldo")
```

and so on to make your own tagged corpus for each class.

It will not be 100% accurate training data but still it will be good enough for training purpose.

Then you can use any ML algorithm for training and testing.